# How to access specific data type in my Methods java

Tags: java

I have many problems in my simple program.

My goal is to create a program that displays the gross and net salary of each employee. I've decided to let the user input the employee's name and I created random value to each salary deductions.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class QuizAndActRecitas {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        employeeName();
        String a = input.readLine();

        salaryEmp();
    }

    //Display 
    public static void employeeName() {
        System.out.print("Enter Employee's Name: ");
    }

    //Salary computations 
    public static void salaryEmp() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        int basicSalary = randomGenerator.nextInt(80000) + 30000;
        System.out.println("Basic Salary: " + "P" + basicSalary);

        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        int allowance = randomGenerator.nextInt(3000) + 2000;
        System.out.println("Monthly Allowance: " + "P" + allowance);

        int houseRent = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000) + 5000;
        System.out.println("House Rent Pay: " + "P" + houseRent);

        int medical = randomGenerator.nextInt(5000) + 3000;
        System.out.println("Medical/Health Allowance: " + "P" + medical);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        int grossSalarry = basicSalary+allowance+houseRent+medical;

        System.out.println("Gross Salary :" + "P"+grossSalarry);
    }

    public static void NetSalary() {

    }
}
```

So, my problem is how can I access the gross salary in the new method NetSalary()? My goal is to create many methods.

I also want to create a new method that will tell the employee's position in the company. Let's say if the employee's salary (this is random) is above 80,000, then it will say (employeesname + "He's the lead programmer")

Comment: Where is the question in your question?

Comment: Read a book son !! We are here to guide you not to do your work

Comment: I;m just asking dude if how can i access that DATA TYPE dad.
Im just exploring , that's just question.. you can just ignore it dad if u think im stupid in asking.. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access variables from another method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123979/access-variables-from-another-method)

Answer (score 0):

Make `grossSalarry` a class level variable.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class QuizAndActRecitas {

    private Double grossSalary;
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others you can declare grossSalary as public and access it anywhere.

You can use a switch case to evaluate the salary level:

```
    switch(grossSalary){
case (greater than 80000);
//(employeesname + "He's the lead programmer")
System.out.println(a + "He's the lead programmer"); 
break;

case(.........
```